# Quadratic optimization with non-constant coefficients

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a series of functions (very similar to convex quadratic equations, see the first comment below) $f_1(x), f_2(x), \dots, f_n(x)$. Each of these functions touches the $x$-axis at $a_i$, which can be different for each function. The functions $f_i$ are such that the derivative on the left of its point $(a_i, 0)$ is different from the derivative on the right of that point. This is because all $f_i$ represent penalty functions which are asymmetric: deviating from the optimum $x = a_i$ results in a different penalty if $x$ is, say, $a_i - 1$ compared to $x$ being $a_i + 1$.

$x$ is a scalar. We have $x \ge 0$, and it is known that $a_i \ge 0$ for all $i$.

The penalties of all functions for a certain $x$ are combined: $F(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x) + \dots + f_n(x)$

We are interested in finding the $x_\text{opt}$ for which $F(x)$ is minimal.

If the derivatives would be the same on the left and the right (and hence the coefficients would be constant), I think we can find the optimal solution analytically: for a convex $f_i(x) = \alpha_ix^2 + \beta_ix +\gamma_iz$, the optimum is $-\beta_i / (2\alpha_i)$, and we can take the average of all these values.

And is this approach still valid for the above described situation? And if so, what is an approach to finding this value analytically / programmatically (in python)?

Comment: You refer to $f_i$ as a "convex quadratic equation". Is it actually a *function* (as it seems from the rest of the question) and is it actually *piecewise quadratic* ($f_i(x) = \max \lbrace f_i^-(x), f_i^+(x) \rbrace$ where $f_i^-()$ and $f_i^+()$ are respectively the penalties on the left and right side of $x=a_i$ and $f_i^-(a_i)=f_i^+(a_i) = 0$)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks!

Comment: $x$ is a scalar variable, correct? Are there any constraints on $x$, or is the optimization unconstrained?

Comment: Indeed, $x$ is a scalar. And the only constraint is $x \ge 0$, and we also know that $a_i \ge 0$ for all $i$. I will update the question.

Comment: Averaging all the individual minimizers would *not* minimize the sum, sum of squares or square root of sum of squares of the individual functions.

Comment: Indeed, I only considered the case where all weights are being 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved either analytically or numerically.

Let's assume without loss of generality that the breakpoints are numbered in increasing order: $0 \le a_1 \le \dots \le a_n < \infty.$ The first step is to evaluate $F$ at all the breakpoints $0, a_1, \dots, a_n.$ Next, find the minimum value (either analytically or via numerical method such as gradient search) in each *open* interval $(0, a_1),$ $(a_1, a_2),$ ..., $(a_n, \infty).$ Since each of the component functions is quadratic in the interior of every interval, this should be straightforward. Now compare the values at the breakpoints and the interior minimizers and pick a winner.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. If I think about it: there will be an (at least one) interval $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ in which the derivate is zero, and determining this value should be very straightforward. Is that correct? And I am wondering, is the solution unique (given that all weights are positive)?

Comment: It is likely but not certain that there will be a zero derivative for $F$ somewhere. To see why it is not certain, consider the case with only one point ($a_1 = 1$) and with $f_1(x)=x^2 - 3x + 2$ when $x<a_1$ and $f_1(x)=x^2-x$ when $x > a_1.$ For $x < a_1$ the derivative $2x-3$ is negative and for $x > a_1$ the derivative $2x-1$ is positive. The minimum is at $a_1,$ but the derivative is never 0.

Comment: As for the solution being unique, I believe it is, assuming that each $f_i$ is decreasing for $x< a_i$ and increasing for $x>a_i,$ as seems likely. For $x<a_1,$ all the $f_i$ are decreasing and therefore $F$ is. As $x$ increases, the slope of each $f_i$ is monotonically increasing (switching from negative to positive at $a_i$), so the slope of $F$ is also monotonically increasing. That makes $F$ unimodal.

Comment: I am not supposed to say just thanks in a comment, but since I cannot upvote: thanks a lot!

Comment: Accepting the answer is akin to an upvote (and worth a few more karma points).